# "Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2, salesforce2salesforce, sfrestrequest

I am following web-server authorization flow for establishing the connection between one org to another org. as a 1st step i have get authorization code,when i am proceeding to 2nd step, getting above error.
I have already set remote site access setting is as follow in source org.
https://login.salesforce.com, and https://ap1.salesforce.com as a instance url.
my request code is:

```
//getting authorization code
string codeparam=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('code');
Http h = new Http();
String body='grant_type=authorization_code&code='+codeparam+'&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URL;
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
// req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
// req.setHeader('accept','application/json');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(body);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

.......anybody can help.
screen shot my remote access setting

[image]

**can any one get this
i am not getting the login page,its directly ask for approve the page , as a user from which i am sending the request..if i changed the user to source user then it logout me from destination org ..if i logout then i cannot get that authorization code. :(  here is snap shot of that stage..**[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screen shot of the Remote Site Settings screen? Is it `https` or `http`?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta :i didn't get why its telling like "Remote site Setting.endpoint...i am setting enpoint in request.setEndpoint

Comment: Is this in the _client_ org or the _service_ org?

Comment: @user320..my source org(service org) ankushsomani09@gmail.com
destination org(client org) ankushsomani09@yahoo.co.in
now you will get clear image of my problem

Comment: Don't want to make it an answer, as I'm not 100%, but I thought the endpoint should be your environment url... https://na*.salesforce.com... where the asterisk is your server number.

Comment: @user320, i got some issue,actually in web-server flow for getting authorization code.the complete url i need to redirct using pagerefernce OR i have to make an HttpRequest  by setting endpoint..if i am using PageReference..it is connecting to my org itself..any solution or idea...where i am wrong.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score 0):

Have you define your org from where you are requesting, in Connected App to the Resource.If you are using salesforce org1 as a client and salesforce org2 as a Server than Define Connected app in salesforce org2 which you are using as a Server.